# AWS RDS - grant permission to change master password

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I want to setup IAM policy to grant permission for changing only RDS master password. I followed this document: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonrds.html but I didn't find any strict policy for RDS master password.
I see we use this action: rds:ModifyDBInstance but this action is much larger than the requirement. Anyone can suggest for me

Comment: There is no other action than `rds:ModifyDBInstance` for that.

Comment: thanks Marcin, but can we use resources, conditional to limit for only master password and nothing else?

Comment: I don't think so. List of available conditions for RDS can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonrds.html#amazonrds-db. You can changed the admin password via SQL if that helps.